# How to redirect a user in Perl CGI

Tags: perl

How can I redirect a user in Perl?...

I've tried many of the methods online, although none seem to work.

For example I tried this: (Although it doesnt seem to work. Just prints out on the page "Location: {url....}"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

$q = CGI->new;
print $q->header("text/html");
$url = $q->param('url');

print "Location: $url\n\n";
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks,

Comment: Where did you find this method online? `Location` should be in the header, not after you send a header. (This is also clearly answered in the docs for the CGI module to begin with...)

Comment: Rather than trying random online examples, why not read [the module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the print `$q-header("text/html");`

Answer (score 1):

You included the Location header in the body rather than in the header, and you never set the proper response code.

The module's documentation has a section titled [GENERATING A REDIRECTION HEADER](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.64/lib/CGI.pm#GENERATING_A_REDIRECTION_HEADER) which shows how do to build the header.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw( );

my $q = CGI->new();
my $url = $q->param('url');
print $q->redirect($url);
```

Comment: (Always use `use strict; use warnings;`)

Answer (score 1):

Why load a module when you can simply make:

```
print("Status: 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: $url\n\n");
```

Or eventually a little more respectful:

```
print("Status: 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: $url\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n");
```

For a 302, replace by "302 Found".